# Python Pandas, Dataframe and reading from excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I merge data with similar values reading from an excel file?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("testfile.xlsx")
print(df)
```

File example: testdata.xlsx

```
Identifier   Dates
123456       1/1/2021
789101       2/2/2021
221342       3/3/2021
231344       1/1/2021
134562       2/2/2021
135650       2/2/2021
135677       2/2/2021
2246         1/1/2021
24682        3/3/2021
245684       1/1/2021
```

Output data wanted (merge the data corresponding to a certain date):

```
2/2/2021   789101 134562 135650 135677  
1/1/2021   245684   2246 231344
3/3/2021   24682  221342
```

Comment: you want to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Do you want separate columns for each of the fields? (If so this is a pivot)

Comment: No I want add all the data having the same dates into one line. For example, for the date 2/2/2021, it has multiple Identifiers, I want all the identifiers for 2/2/2021 in one line and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your problem?

```
df.groupby(['Dates'])['Identifier'].apply(list)
```

```
Dates
1/1/2021      [123456, 231344, 2246, 245684]
2/2/2021    [789101, 134562, 135650, 135677]
3/3/2021                     [221342, 24682]
Name: Identifier, dtype: object
```

---

If you dont want this as a list, but as a string with spaces separated, as you indicate in your question, then try this -

```
df.astype({'Identifier':str}).groupby(['Dates'])['Identifier'].apply(' '.join)
```

```
Dates
1/1/2021      123456 231344 2246 245684
2/2/2021    789101 134562 135650 135677
3/3/2021                   221342 24682
Name: Identifier, dtype: object
```

Comment: I want add all the data having the same dates into one line. For example, for the date 2/2/2021, it has multiple Identifiers, I want all the identifiers for 2/2/2021 in one line and so on. –

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the approach above? I believe it solves what you mention in your comment above.

Comment: I did but it didnt work

Comment: could you elaborate on why it didnt work? what is the output you are getting? did you try running it with the dummy data that you have posted yourself?